Unable to use Internal CA / Public Cert with RabbitMQ for Client Connections
We are currently using RabbitMQ with SSL on a Windows server using certificates generated in OpenSSL (self signed).  This consists of the CA, Server and Client certificate that our app uses to connect to the Virtual Host.
We want to use either certificates generated from an internal CA or a certificate that we could get from Comodo etc.
I've been through the RabbitMQ guide and all I can see is how to use OpenSSL, rather than any other method.
I can get the UI to use a genuine certificate from our internal CA / Comodo, but cannot get this to work with the client certificate.
Has anyone successfully managed to set this up?
Thanks.

I try it but not consistency SSL client test by node.js, sometimes works, some time did not works.
